# General nilpotent matrix to upper right matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible to explicitly give the basis transform matrix $Y$ for transforming a nilpotent 2-by-2 matrix $A$ to a matrix, whose only nonzero entry is in the upper right corner?

$Y^{-1}AY=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & a \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$, with $a$ in general $\neq1$. Reminding a bit to the Jordan normal form.

Comment: Do you mean to ask if it is possible to do so in terms of the entries of $A$?

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to find $Y$ is as follows:

Select any vector $u$ such that $Au \neq 0$.  Let $u$ and $Au$ be the columns of $Y$ (in that order).  Then
$$
YAY^{-1} = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}
$$

So, in general: suppose that $A = \pmatrix{a&b\\c&d} \neq 0$.   If either $a$ or $c$ is non-zero, select
$$
Y = \pmatrix{1&a\\0&c}
$$
Otherwise, select
$$
Y = \pmatrix{0&b\\1&d}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since the only Jordan Canonical form of a non-zero $\;2\times 2\;$ nilpotent matrix is precisely

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

then yes: no wonder it reminds you a lot of the JCF, and thus you can take $\;Y\;$ to be the matrix formed by the eigenvalue (the only one up to a scalar multiple) and a generalized eigenvalue.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A$ is nilpotent. Then it has a non-trivial kernel. If $\dim\ker A=2$, there's nothing to do, so assume $\dim\ker A=1$, and let $v$ span the kernel. Then choose $u$ such that $Au=v$, and represent $A$ with respect to the basis $\{v,u\}$.